# Understanding object initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I accidenatlly forget to write braces while initializing array:

```
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    A(int a) { std::cout << "A(" << a << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a[3] =  A(2), A(3);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a900da63cce76ac1)

Output:

```
A(2)
A(2)
A(2)
A(3)
```

And this's correct, as far as I got. `N4257::12.6.1/2`:

> ***Braces can be elided in the initializer-list for any aggregate***, even
>   if the aggregate has members of a class type with user-defined type
>   conversions

But braced initiliazation has the different side-effect:

```
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    A(int a) { std::cout << "A(" << a << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a[3] = { A(2), A(3) };
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66a22f2425547d7f)

Output:

```
A(2)
A(3)
A()
```

Couldn't you explain that difference?

Comment: `A a[3] =  A(2), A(3);` defines two variables - one named `a` which is an array of thee `A`s, and one named `A` of type `A`, constructed from 3. In other words, it's equivalent to `A a[3] =  A(2); A A(3);` , and not at all similar to `A a[3] = { A(2), A(3) };`

Comment: Im not entirely sure about this, but I believe some compilers might not provide elided { } on array initializations, or because it compiles a version of C++ where this was not supported. Test this on C11 compliant

Comment: i am getting error on clang: array initializer must be an initializer list

Comment: Not all braces can be elided; see 8.5.1 (referenced in the paragraph you quoted). In particular, the outermost pair can't be.

Comment: For int b[3] = int(2), int(3); g++ reports an error - array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: No error when written as, int b[3] = { int(2), int(3) };

Comment: Interesting, error is reported for primitive types not for used defined ones.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're probably right. But what do they mean __Braces can be elided [...]__ then?

Comment: The passage you cite is in a non-normative note. Also, you didn't quote it in full - you omitted the "see 8.5.1" part. Section 8.5.1 explains in great detail when and how braces can be elided. That note doesn't mean "any and all braces can be elided". My guess is, this note was added to highlight the difference with C++03, where, if I recall correctly, a struct with a member of user-defined type was not considered an aggregate in the first place (and thus could not be brace-initialized at all).

Answer (score 4):

N4527 § 8.5 [dcl.init]

> 17 The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being
>   initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly
>   parenthesized) expression, the source type is not deﬁned.
>
> — (17.1) If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
> — (17.2) If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
>
> — (17.3) If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of char16_t, an array of char32_t, or an
>   array of wchar_t, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.
>
> — (17.4) If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
>
> — (17.5) Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.
>
> [Other irrelevant bullets omitted]

`A a[3] =  A(2)` falls into (17.5), so your program is ill-formed. Apparently [g++ has a bug in this case](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60009). [clang correctly rejects your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e12517b015cb8b).